# Using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];, but modify for www

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using some code like this to grab the URL from an inbound link:

```
$inbound_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

//then do some stuff writing the url to a database table, but....
//ONLY IF the url doesn't already exist in the table
```

Let's say the link comes in from the same website, same webpage, but different only in the www.  So I get this:
1) http://www.mysite.com/page.html
2) http://mysite.com/page.html

This shows up twice in my table since one has the www and one doesn't.

Is there a way to parse the results of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; to either:
1) add www. where it's missing, OR
2) strip everything of ...http://...www. or ..http://

Thanks in advance as always.

Comment: Note that HTTP_REFERER isn't always sent by the user agent

Comment: Sure, there are a number of way to do this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just to be clear, `http://mysite.com` and `http://www.mysite.com` *could be different websites*. They don't necessarily have to point to the same host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. Some simple string manipulation and replacement should be all you need to remove the `www` from any URL -

```
$inbound_url = str_replace('http://www','http://',$inbound_url);
```

As defined in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) -

> `str_replace()` - Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

Notice that I'm including the `http://` in the search so that any other occurrence of the string `www`  URL will remain untouched.

Comment: Of course!  Not sure why I didn't try that, must've been having a brain freeze.  Worked perfectly, thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
$d = array_shift( explode( '.', str_replace('www.', '', parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST )) ) );
echo $d; //stackoverflow
```

or you can also use

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php function